# How to move into next tab using Tab key of keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I want to create functionality when user use tab key for moving in to next tab. Every tab contains some text boxes. When user in last text box of tab 1 when it press the tab key, it will go into next text box of tab2. I am creating tab using plain HTML css and jQuery. I am not using tab functionality of jQuery UI but it is latest jquery. The below is my HTML. I am creating tab using ul and li. How I move into next li when my tab in first text box. The tabs contains like dropdown,checkboxes,texboxes. Note : i am not using tabindex due to some issue. i want to create using jquery)

**html**

```
<ul class='tabs'>
        <li><a href='#tab1'>Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href='#tab2'>Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href='#tab3'>Tab 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id='tab1'>
        <ul class= "set2"> 
            <li>  test 1<asp:TextBox runat="server"  ID="test1" /></li>
            <li>  test 2<asp:TextBox runat="server"  ID="test2" /></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id='tab3'>
        <ul class= "set2"> 
            <li>  test 3<asp:TextBox runat="server"  ID="test3" /></li>
            <li>  test 4<asp:TextBox runat="server"  ID="test4" /></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id='tab3'>
        <ul class= "set"> 
            <li>  test 5<asp:TextBox runat="server"  ID="test5" /></li>
            <li>  test 6<asp:TextBox runat="server"  ID="test6" /></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

**script**

```
$(document).on('keypress',function(e) {
 var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 
 if (keyCode == 9) {       //if the key pressed was 'tab'...
    e.preventDefault(); 
    //how to focus on the next tab, 
    //remember to select the very first tab when you reach the last tab!
  } 
});
```

**CSS**

```
* {padding:0; margin:0;}

    html {
        background:url(/img/tiles/wood.png) 0 0 repeat;
        padding:15px 15px 0;
        font-family:sans-serif;
        font-size:14px;
    }

    p, h3 { 
        margin-bottom:15px;
    }

    div {
        padding:10px;
        width:600px;
        background:#fff;
    }

    .tabs li {
        list-style:none;
        display:inline;
    }

    .tabs a {
        padding:5px 10px;
        display:inline-block;
        background:#666;
        color:#fff;
        text-decoration:none;
    }

    .tabs a.active {
        background:#fff;
        color:#000;
    }
```

Comment: Are you using jquery-ui tabs?

Comment: no,simple jquery html css

Comment: tabindex should do it for you.

Comment: If you could put together a jsFiddle for us, we'd be sooo happy.